# VBARuntime error 1004

Tags: excel, vba

I’m attempting to write a macro that will filter a set of data by two criteria and then copy and paste that data into a new sheet. I have it working so that it creates the new sheet and adds the header row but I keep getting a runtime error for the following If statement and I can’t for the life of me figure out why.

```
If sh.Cells(nRows, 8).Value = "PS" And sh.Cells(nRows, 11).Value = "Key Player" Then
```

Can anyone help? I’ve copied the full code below.

```
Option Explicit
Sub CopyPSStakeholders()
Dim sh      As Worksheet
Dim DestSh  As Worksheet
Dim StartRow As Long
Dim i       As Integer
Dim headers() As Variant
Dim nRows   As Long

Dim LastRow As Long

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With

'Delete the PS Stakeholders sheet if it exists.
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
On Error Resume Next

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("PS Stakeholders").Delete
On Error GoTo 0
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

'Add a new PS Stakeholders worksheet.
Set DestSh = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
DestSh.Name = "PS Stakeholders"

Set sh = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Stakeholders")

'Insert header row.
headers() = Array("Key Player - Post", "Key Player - UID", "Actively Involve - Post", "Actively Involve - UID", "Keep Informed - Post", "Keep Informed - UID")

With DestSh.Cells
    .Rows(1).Value = ""      'This will clear out row 1
    For i = LBound(headers()) To UBound(headers())
        .Cells(1, 1 + i).Value = headers(i)
    Next i
    .Rows(1).Font.Bold = True
End With

'Count the last used row of data
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

'Set the first row of data
nRows = 2

'Filter and copy/paste
With sh.Cells
    Do
        If sh.Cells(nRows, 8).Value = "PS" And sh.Cells(nRows, 11).Value = "Key Player" Then
            DestSh.Cells(nRows, 1).Value = sh.Cells(nRows, 3).Value
        End If
        nRows = nRows + 1
    Loop Until nRows = LastRow
End With

ExitTheSub:
Application.Goto DestSh.Cells(1)

' AutoFit the column width in the summary sheet.
DestSh.Columns.AutoFit

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
End With

With Sheets("Active")
    .Visible = True
    .Activate
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Are there any worksheet error codes (e.g. #DIV/0!, #N/A, etc) in columns H or K?

Comment: not your problem but, `With sh.Cells` is not doing anything as you never reference it inside the block.

Comment: What does error say?

Comment: `Loop Until nRows > LastRow` would be safer.  Are you sure your LastRow is getting set correctly?  You don't specify a sheet here LastRow = `Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row` so are you sure the value isn't 1, in which case your loop goes off the bottom of the sheet?  A `For Next` would be more appropriate for this use case.  And as @ScottCraner points out you seem to have an issue with your `With` blocks.